# Replace 2D-matrix by "double-index List<>"?

Tags: c#, types

I'm implementing the Floyd-Warshal algorithm from [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floyd-warshall-algorithm-dp-16/), as proposed in [this other StackExchange question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/443544), in a C# environment.

Everything is working fine, but the used graph datatype is not very useful (it's a basic 4x4 2D matrix), hereby the example from the website itself:

```
int[,] graph_matrix = {{  0,   5, INF,   8},
                       {INF,   0,   3, INF},
                       {INF, INF,   0,   1},
                       {INF, INF, INF,   0}};
```

I would like to create a graph, which consists of a large number of vertices, which are more or less only connected to their closest neighbour, like in this image:

[image]

There are about 600 vertices in my graph, and having a 600x600 matrix might blow up my memory, so I'm looking for a datatype, like a `double_index_List<int>` where I could do something like:

```
double_index_List<int> graph_connections = new double_index_List<int>();
for (int index=0, index <= 600; index++)
    graph_connections.insertAt(index,index) = 0;

// make the connections between all subsequent points
graph_connections.insertAt(1, 2)   = 5000;
graph_connections.insertAt(2, 3)   = 5100;
graph_connections.insertAt(3, 4)   =  600;
...
graph_connections.insertAt(600, 1) = 4800;

// foresee the possibility that some non-subsequent vertices in the graph are reachable.
graph_connections.insertAt(100,  20) = 4200;
graph_connections.insertAt(200, 124) =  500;
graph_connections.insertAt(320, 240) =  600;
...
graph_connections.insertAt(600, 540) =  480;
```

The idea is that I have a function, like:

```
// Explanation: If graph_connections(x, y) has been created, then return that entry. 
//              If not, return the default value (being `INF`).
graph_connections.get(x, y, INF)
```

Does such "doubly indexed List" or "double-index List" exist in C#?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<TKey, int>`, where `TKey` is either an `int[2]` or a two-int tuple.  I've normally called these a _sparse matrix_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).  One of the nice things about C# is that you can have _indexers_, even 2D indexers.  That way, you can access a class that implements a sparse matrix just like a normal matrix with `mySparseMatrix[x,y]` syntax.  By the way, a 600x600 integer matrix is not insanely large, it's a bit under 150 kBytes; big but it's not going to cause the lights on your computer to dim

Comment: It turns out that my multiplication skill suck early on Monday mornings.  It's "under 1.5 MBytes", not under "150 kBytes").  Still big, but not huge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> having a 600x600 matrix might blow up my memory

Why? such a matrix should only require 1.44Mb of memory, that should really not be a problem, even on 32 bit systems.

> Does such "doubly indexed List" or "double-index List" exist in C#?

What you are describing is essentially a *sparse matrix*, there is no such builtin. But you might want to take a look at [Math.Net SparseMatrix](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/SparseMatrix.htm).

However, it would not be very difficult to write your own based on a dictionary

```
var mySparseMatrix = new Dictionary<(int x, int y), int>();
mySparseMatrix[(1, 2)]   = 5000;
var value = mySparseMatrix.TryGet((1, 2), out var r) ? r : 0
```

**Remark:**
The previous lines of source are based on `System.ValueTuple`. The more recent .Net frameworks cover this by default but in case yours doesn't, there's a Nuget library "[System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/)" which can be used for this purpose.

Note that ValueTuple that this uses does not have a good `GetHashCode` implementation, so the performance of this will be poor. You should probably implement your own Point/Vector2i type with GetHashCode & Equals implemented. Or maybe use [System.Drawing.Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-7.0). You should probably also wrap the dictionary in a custom class to provide the interface you want.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've used your source code, creating a dictionary, but it seems not to work. I get compilation error CS8179 "Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple 2`' is not defined or imported", and the proposed solution (putting the next line in the constructor of the `Dictionary` is also not a solution. Can you correct your source code?

Comment: @Dominique If you are using an old version of .Net you may need to import [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/), and you may need to edit the [langversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) to use the compact `(x,y)` syntax. But the example is provided as an *example of the approach*. I would not recommend just copy pasting it.

Comment: @Dominique You need to use nuget to add the ValueTuple reference. But as I mentioned, you should probably use some other point-like type consisting of two integers. I always prefer to use the latest versions, so upgrade to .Net 7?

Comment: Ok, I've corrected my corrections :-)